# rails standalone installer package for rail 3.xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find rails standalone installer package for the rails v.3.x.x?
I know I can use gem command and specify a particular version to download.
Is that available to download on some website like rubyforge?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
git checkout v3.1.1
```

List all versions:

```
git tag -l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using windows, you can use [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails